# How do sites like Wix translate their UI manipulation into code?

Tags: javascript, velo

**For example**:
*When you add a new text object and style it and make it do something on click*.

Does it use DOM Manipulation in some way or does it write new files or just writes to json data so that their engine can take the data and translate it into a website? How does it do all that?

Comment: This is a really broad question. My guess is they create some sort of tree that their parser reads and translates into HTML / CSS for the browser to understand. But as to how it all interacts, that would take a long time to reverse engineer and maybe not even that interesting at the end of it all.